# safe way to stop a thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

```
public class thread extends Thread {

    static volatile boolean done = false;// volatile keyword is used            

@Override
public void run() {
    while (!done) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

            try {
                thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(currentThread());
            System.out.println("1st thread>> " + i);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread th = new Thread(new thread(),"mythread");
    th.start();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        thread.sleep(400);
        System.out.println(currentThread());
        System.out.println("2nd thread>> " + i);
        if (i == 4) {
            done = true;// safe way to stop a thread
            break;
        }
    }

   }
  }
```

I am using  volatile static variable here.Is it a safe way to stop a thread and also
when I print currentThread() method I get the output like Thread[mythread,5,main]
what does the 5 and main refer to??

Comment: You're asking two questions here. :-)

Comment: lol seems like I am saving some database space for stackoverflow. I am playing secret Santa for them ;)

Comment: Well, your second question is tucked in at the bottom and is likely to be either ignored, or answered and the other one ignored. (e.g., the answer by Eric Rosenburg) In order to get more focused answers and not waste people's time (including your own), you should consider asking two separate questions next time. Database space is cheap; time is not. This is just unsolicited (but hopefully helpful) advice, not a reprimand or criticism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a safe way to stop a thread, but there is no reason for the variable to be static: you want to stop one thread, not all threads of the same class. 
Moreover, there is a more standard and less fragile way to stop a thread: interrupting it.

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() {
        ...
    }
}

...

th.interrupt();
```

This has the additional advantage that a thread which is sleeping or waiting, or blocked in an interruptible IO method will be woken up with an InterruptedException. When such an exception happens, it means that the thread should stop running, so you shouldn't swallow the exception as you did. Instead, you should return from the run method as fast as possible:

```
try {
    thread.sleep(200);
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: actually i wanted to construct a loading form in a separate thread will the interrupt method work with that ??? I wanted to know about the pros and cons

Comment: Yes. Check for the interrupt status flag using isInterrupted rather than checking for a volatile flag.

Comment: Ok thank you JB :) I got it and one more thing how can I use a thread from a thread pool in java. I actually I had developed a similar loading form for windows forms using threads from thread pool and using a static variable to stop it.It worked well then so thought if it is ok to do the same in java.

Comment: @JB Nizet: what if the thread has missed listening to interrupt call, the volatile variable is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Thread to toString, which is what is being called when you do System.out.println(currentThread()) prints out the thread name, priority, and thread group.

I'm assuming you are trying to interrupt the thread for something other then a normal completion, so why not just use Thread.interrupt() and Thread.isInterrupted()?

Comment: Thank you for the answer also is the use of volatile static variable a safe way to stop a thread. If there is another more safer way please let me know :)